# Issues loading data into UITableView from API call

Tags: ios, swift, api, uitableview, alamofire

I am new to ios development and running into issue loading data from an API call to a UITableView. The app is going to serve as ordering system. To get data into each cell of the tableView I have a button on a viewController that sends a post request with the id of the item and the id is matched to items in memory on the server. I have a view controller that has a tableView of the current ordered items which is where my problem is.

I have two other view controllers (`BeerListTableViewController` and `CocktailListTableViewController`) with tableViews in them loaded with the items that you can order. These tableViews are loading correctly with their respective items. When pressing on a cell in either tableView I perform a segue to another viewController (`BeerDetailViewController` or `CocktailDetailViewController`) where the item is shown and an "Place Order" button is shown. The place order button sends the item to the server where it is added to the array of orders and then popViewController to get back to the tableView. I have verified that the items are getting added correctly. In both `BeerListTableViewController` and `CocktailListTableViewController` I have added a barButtonItem "Orders" which segues to `DrinkOrderTableView` and this is where my ISSUE lies. In this tableView only the orders from `BeerDetailViewController` are showing. I have included code from the xcode project and my node index.js file. Any help is much appreciated!
[image: screenshot of storyboard]

```swift
class DrinkOrdersTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var orders: [Order] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.title = "Current Orders"

        fetchAllCurrentOrders { orders in
            self.orders = orders!
            print(self.orders)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    private func fetchAllCurrentOrders(completion: @escaping([Order]?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request("http://127.0.0.1:4000/orders", method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else { return completion(nil) }
                guard let rawInventory = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]?] else { return completion(nil) }
                let currentOrders = rawInventory.compactMap { ordersDict -> Order? in
                    guard let orderId = ordersDict!["id"] as? String,
                        let orderStatus = ordersDict!["status"] as? String,
                        var pizza = ordersDict!["pizza"] as? [String: Any] else { return nil }
                    pizza["image"] = UIImage(named: pizza["image"] as! String)

                    return Order(
                        id: orderId,
                        pizza: Pizza(data: pizza),
                        status: OrderStatus(rawValue: orderStatus)!
                    )

                }
                completion(currentOrders)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func closeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Debugging ROWS", orders.count)
        return orders.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "order", for: indexPath)
        let order = orders[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = order.pizza.name
        cell.imageView?.image = order.pizza.image
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(order.pizza.amount) - \(order.status.rawValue)"
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "orderSegue", sender: orders[indexPath.row] as Order)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "orderSegue" {
            guard let vc = segue.destination as? OrderViewController else { return }
            vc.order = sender as? Order
        }
    }
}
```

link to [server code](https://gist.github.com/Austin-Griffith/4d8265c0a14c8a7150859e713c509003)

Link to screencap of [issue](https://vimeo.com/330941142)

Comment: put your `fetchAllCurrentOrders` method in `viewWillAppear` method and check.

Comment: @Dharmesh I had previously had a villWillAppear method but it did not make a difference so I put ```fetchAllCurrentOrders``` back to the ```viewDidLoad``` method

Comment: Are you getting correct data from server when you visit that screen again?

Comment: @Dharmesh Yes I am still getting the items ordered from the beer selection tableView but I am not getting the items from the cocktail selection tableView.

Comment: Have you tried it on postman with post and get request?

Comment: @Dharmesh No but I have been verifying the data with log prints to command line. I just send orders from each of the tableViews in the simulator and got this output [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/eCRVg1N.png) The items printed are in the orders array in my index.js file

Comment: Your `Debugging ROWS` printing `1` that means it only has one value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191997/discussion-between-austin-griffith-and-dharmesh).